# How do I organize a Maven project which holds two separate applications?

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on an web service / API and a corresponding API client. Both are Maven projects.

I'm currently working on these two as separate projects. However, I've come to believe that it may be better to merge these two projects into one because...

1. ...the API client is worthless without the API - it can't function
   without it.
2. ...integration tests for the API are currently in the API client 
   project. I'm running integration tests using the API resource 
   abstractions available in the API client project.

If I merge these two projects into one, how do I keep these projects separated within the same Maven project? I'd like to be able to build **either** the API or the API client independently of each other.

Comment: Wouldn't you want the API project to be a dependency of the client project? That way, the API has it's own POM with only it's own dependencies - which means it'll compile on it's own.

Comment: @nbokmans in reality it will be the other way around. That is, the client will depend on the API. However, not sure if the API can run the integration tests of the client (during build) just by making the API depending on the client?

Answer (score 0):

I think that separation of projects generally is a good practice. You always have greater scope and flexibility if you're building end system from the small components. Also, changes in one module will not affect others. Moreover, if you would like to add second implementation for the client, separation will be better choice. I definitely vote for keeping them separate.

At for the merge: I think even if your client has a small functionality you should think twice, before merging.

If you still believe in the merge, for the build, I suggest you to use [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to customize your build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working with a multi-module maven project pattern almost exactly the same as yours.

```
parent pom
+---API
+---WS
+---client-lib
```

There is absolutely no problem in having two *artifacts* or *libraries* as different *modules* in the same maven *project*, rather than two separate *projects*.

To configure, simply set the parent pom packaging to `pom`, establish the sub-folders and use a `<modules>` definition to list each sub-module in the correct build order.

How to build them separately? You simply go into the sub-directory and build from there.

```
cd client-lib
mvn clean install
```

There is a caveat - the dependencies of client-lib need to have already been built once. But for incremental changes, you can just run maven again in the sub-directory (sub-module).

As for running integration tests that you mentioned, there is also a plus that all the sub modules are available for the integration tests. You can even add a sub-module named integration-tests.

```
parent pom
+---API
+---WS
+---client-lib
+---integration-tests
```

Good luck further with maven!